# Create/Manage AWS SQS producer and consumer for dynamic queues in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a use case in which I need to create AWS SQS queues dynamically for each product on my platform for a short period.

**What have I tried**:

- I have already considered [Virtual Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-temporary-queues.html), but NodeJS SDK doesn't support it yet based on the [AWS GitHub issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client/issues/15).
- Merely the message group ID concept in an AWS SQS FIFO queue won't help because I need parallelism across different message group IDs without scaling the number of consumers (at least up to an extent).
- I created this working [NodeJS SQS Demo project](https://github.com/sbmaggarwal/Node-SQS-Demo) for one static queue.

But how do I manage multiple queues dynamically? Creating Producers is easy by following these steps:

1. Code running for a product ID (product ID is message group ID here)
2. Code checks if a Queue already exists for a Product ID from Cache/DB
3. If it exists, publish the message. If it does not exist, create a queue, then publish the message.

But how do I programmatically manage consumers? If I have [this SQS Consumer](https://github.com/sbmaggarwal/Node-SQS-Demo/blob/main/consumer/sqsConsumer.js), how can I make it work for different Queue URLs? Do I call `start` again and again by passing Queue URLs? How do I reference this consumer so they can later be removed from memory?

We can assume that deleting a queue is not a problem when use case is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I solved it myself. As described [here in code](https://github.com/sbmaggarwal/Node-SQS-Demo/blob/main/routes/endpoints.js), I did the following:

1. Call Create Queue (no need to check if queue already exists, AWS responds to `createQueue` in exactly the same fashion even if queue already exists, which saves us an operation to check if queue exists).
2. Send message to new queue (URL for new queue received in response of `createQueue` operation).
3. In the callback for `sendMessage`, use the `receiveMessage` with a `WaitTimeSeconds` of 100-250 milliseconds so that we can ensure message is received.

Read about [receiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property) before you use it, sometimes **it won't return a message if there are too few messages**, we need to retry on our own in that case.

Comment: how did you programmatically manage consumers?

Comment: @Smartniggs As I mentioned above, I only needed short-lived consumers. And I knew exactly when there will be messages, at that time I called `sqs.receiveMessage(params` explicitly.